# Crop video using OpenCV 3.0 for Java

Tags: java, opencv, crop, video-editing

I have a given video and rectangle. My aim is to crop the video such that the new video only consits of the part which is given by the rectangle (see [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnshm.png)). Is there an easy solution using Java and OpenCV?
My first idea was to extract every single frame of the video, cut it and save it to some folder. Then I would create a new video from the given images, however the main problem is that,as far as i know, there is no videoWriter for Java. Is there maybe a better way to solve this problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use ROI via Rects. I'm not sure how to implement the same in Java, but this is the equivalent implementation in C++:

```
cap>>img;
Rect r=Rect(0,60,200,300);//200x300 rect from point (0,60)
Mat img_r=img(r);
```

img_r now contains the part of the image within the rect. You can use VideoWriter class to save the frames of img_r in a video file.